# Is there a way to restart the mission in Thief?

Tags: thief

I'm currently in the first Thief mission right after the prologue. My only savegame is after I was caught once, so the bonus objective is marked as failed.

Since I played maybe 5 minutes of the mission I'd like to restart it, but can't find any option for this. Did the developers seriously forgot to add a "mission start" autosave and/or a "restart mission" option or am I blind?

Comment: I know there's a replay mission button when you finish the mission, but not sure if you can do it in the middle of the mission.

Answer (score 8):

The savegames are nested. In the "load" mean I first had to select the current save slot:

[image: load step 1]

Afterwards I got a list of all savegames, including one to restart the chapter:

[image: load step 2]